# undefined method `model_name' for NewThread::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I read hundreds of questions with same issue but couldn't figure it out. here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@new_thread, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my controller:

```
def new
    @new_thread = NewThread.new
  end



 def create
    @new_thread = NewThread.new(new_thread_params)
    # Save the object
    if @new_thread.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
      flash[:notice] = "Thread created."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      @new_thread = NewThread.order('id ASC')
      render('new')
    end
  end

 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def new_thread_params
      params.require(:new_thread).permit(:title, :description, :user_id)
    end
```

my model:

```
class NewThread < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :replies, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :like_counts, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :dislike_counts, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :new_thread_flags, :dependent => :destroy

    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_presence_of :description
end
```

my routes associated with new_thread:

```
                         GET    /new_threads(.:format)                                 new_threads#index
                         POST   /new_threads(.:format)                                 new_threads#create
          new_new_thread GET    /new_threads/new(.:format)                             new_threads#new
         edit_new_thread GET    /new_threads/:id/edit(.:format)                        new_threads#edit
              new_thread GET    /new_threads/:id(.:format)                             new_threads#show
                         PATCH  /new_threads/:id(.:format)                             new_threads#update
                         PUT    /new_threads/:id(.:format)                             new_threads#update
                         DELETE /new_threads/:id(.:format)                             new_threads#destroy
                         DELETE /reply_flags/:id(.:format)                             reply_flags#destroy
      new_threads_search POST   /new_threads/search(.:format)                          new_threads#search
                    root GET    /                                                      new_threads#list
```

everything looks just fine. when i submit my form with empty fields i get this :

```
undefined method `model_name' for NewThread::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class
```

otherwise it works just fine. i use the same form partial for update and there validations work too. i am using rails 4.

Comment: At which line did the error is pointing?

Comment: <%= form_for(@new_thread, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %> please check update of question.

Comment: Can you post the create action of your controller?

Comment: see update! btw i was using <%= form_for(@new_thread) do |f| %> when i was using common partial. i guess the current one doesn't make difference if i am using it only for create.

Comment: try changing this line `render('new')` to `render 'new'`

Comment: doesn't make any difference. i guess neither its suppose to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here, where you initialize a new `@new_thread` after the save fails:

```
@new_thread = NewThread.order('id ASC')
```

What are you expecting to happen there? Perhaps you meant this?

```
@new_thread = NewThread.order('id ASC').first
```

Without choosing *one* of the `NewThread`s, the view will try to render the whole *collection* of them.

Comment: got it. actually its @new_threads = NewThread.order('id ASC') knowing a typo wasted my 3 hrs doesn't feel great. i guess i was never looking for the error at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line:

```
@new_thread = NewThread.order('id ASC')
```

Otherwise when save fails you will give user different model to edit. You have already assigned `@new_thread` so all will work.